# Left div does reduce width when hover over right one

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I am trying to create this animation where when I hover over left `div` it changes it width to 100% and at the same time right `div` will set width to 0%. Same thing in vice versa should happen when I hover over right `div`.

But When I hover over right `div` only the width of right `div` tag changes to 100% and width of left `div` does not change and that makes the right `div` go under the left so can anyone help me with this.

I am putting the entire code below

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'open-sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbarli {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color:
}

.navbarui {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbardiv {
  background-color: #282828;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

nav div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

nav a: hover {
  color: #d8d8d8;
}

.mycontainer {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background-color: ;
}

.footer1 {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #282828;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  clear: both;
}

.divsecl {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  float: left;
}

.divsecr {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  float: right;
}

.divsecl:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.divsecl:hover+.divsecr {
  width: 0%;
}

.divsecr:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.divsecr:hover+.divsecl {
  width: 0%;
}

.resultitem {
  background: #48e;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.resultitem:hover {
  background: #59f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <div class="divsecl resultitem">
    <h1>Skills</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="divsecr resultitem">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply because `+` works only in one direction and not both

Comment: its vice versa. visa is a credit card company,

Comment: Please simplify your sentence. It takes a long time to read.

Comment: @TemaniAfif So what can I do to get the result, can you provide like a sample code

Comment: check below, already provided ;)

Comment: @Temani Afif: nvm, I reopened it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` selector doesn't work like you expect in both direction. This selector means select element that are **placed immediately after** and thus only work when you hover the first element.

Here is another idea if you want to achieve what you want *(I simplified your code to keep only the relevant part)*

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow:hidden
}

.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  background: blue;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow:hidden
}

.container:hover .b{
  width: 100%;
}

.container:hover .a {
  width: 0%;
}
.a:hover {
  width: 100%!important;
}

.a:hover+.b {
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <h1>Skills</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a bit more CSS to make the "b" container shrink on hover.  So, what Temani Afif said, but add:

```
.a:hover + .b {
  width: 0%!important;    
}
```

Comment: can you explain why this is needed .. !important is not needed here since the CSS is placed at the end. As you can see in my code it working fine